# Code inside OnDataChange executed multiple time

Tags: database, delphi

I have a TDatasource linked to a  TTable and I have some code executed inside Datasource.OnDataChange.

My problem is, when I execute a TTable.First or TTable.Last, the code inside OnDataChange is executed for each record until the cursor reaches the first or last position (I suppose is the same with TTable1.MoveBy).

How can I make sure my code inside OnDataChange is executed only once, at the end of the process ?

Comment: In my tests I could not reproduce the behavior your described. When I call Last what have is a single fire of `OnDataChange`. Maybe something else is influencing your code. My test was like this: I created a new form with a `TTable`, a `TDataSource` and a `TDBGrid` and connected them all. Added a handler to `TDataSource.OnDataChange`. Before calling `Last` I  assigned 0 to a counter and incremented it in `OnDataChange`. After calling Last, showed the counter.

Comment: another advise I can give to you is to abandon BDE...

Comment: Do you have other handlers active on your Datasource or TTable?

Comment: No other handlers active on that Datasource and TTable. I will do the test above suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with a similar situation recently. In my case, as an example, my code in the `OnDataChange` event was intended to adjust the column widths of an associated `TDBGrid` according to the latest data in the associated `Dataset`. I needed this adjustment to occur only when the data changed, but OnDataChange appeared to execute multiple times in succession.

**So, how to make it execute the code only once?**

I chose to use a `Boolean` flag to limit the execution of the code in the OnDataChange event to only when that flag is set to True. Something like this... (basic example code)

```
var
  bLoading: Boolean;

procedure TfrmMain.btnExecuteSQLClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qry.SQL := memo.Lines;
  bLoading := True; // set flag to true so code in OnDataChange will execute
  qry.Open;
end;    

procedure TfrmMain.DataSource1OnDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  if bLoading then // checks if your flag is set to true
  begin
    // insert the code you want to run only once here
    ...
    bLoading := False; // then set flag to false to prevent repetitive execution
  end;
end;
```

I'm not sure if this helps you, and I know it doesn't answer the second part of your question "at the end of the process", but maybe just the idea of using Boolean flags will give you some inspiration to progress with your problem. It's a useful technique, and in the world of multithreaded programming they've even given it a special name. They call it a `mutex`!!! It's just a Boolean flag. Either the door is open, or it's closed. Once it's opened, make sure you shut the door behind you to prevent uninvited guests from crashing the party!